# Pulling in a subset of classes from a sibling project

Tags: java, gradle

In my root project, I have many sub-projects:

- `common`
- `dependant-1`
- `dependant-2`
- ...
- `standalone`

In this scenario, `common` is a shared library. All other projects are dependant on it, with the exception of `standalone`. (`standalone` is actually a standalone client JAR).

What I would like to do is get 5 classes from `common` into the jar file produced in `standalone`. I only need those exact 5 classes (out of ~200) and want to avoid bringing `common` as a full dependency (along with all of `common`'s dependencies). Granted it's an unusual setup, but I don't want to include classes that the client has no business with and the classes I am including just contain `enum` or `static final`.

So far, I have tried the following in the `build.gradle` for `standalone`:

```
jar {
    manifest.attributes(
        // .... Removed
    )

    with project(':common').jar {
        include('com/classpath/ClassA.class')
        include('com/classpath/ClassB.class')
        include('com/classpath/ClassC.class')
        include('com/classpath/ClassD.class')
        include('com/classpath/ClassE.class')
    }

}
```

This works very well for the `standalone` project, but tramples the other projects that were fully dependant on `common`; `common.jar` will now only ever contain the classes listed above, regardless of which dependant project.

(I'm guessing this is expected behaviour: in Gradle's configuration phase, it sees the specific configuration I have for `common` in `standalone` and applies that to `common`).

So, in short, what is the neatest solution to this? I'm thinking that I may need to provide a `configuration` in the `build.gradle` for the `common` project. I'm not sure how to do this yet (RTFM). I just wanted to check that there isn't a better approach to this?

---

**EDIT:** to answer some of alexvetter's questions.

I hadn't yet tried to include them from `build/classes`, but this did the trick (see the accepted answer).

I did consider creating a new `common-base` project. If there were much more than 5 classes that I needed, I absolutely would have gone this way. And yes, I only need the classes at runtime.

Just to clarify the last point... the `standalone` jar file is actually a JAX-WS client jar that we provide to another team. The reason I needed to inlcude these specific classes in the client JAR is so that the client knows what values to give to certain web service method calls. Ideally, I would have replaced all of the included classes with `enum` (like I mentioned, they are literally just `static final` definitions) and JAX-WS would have looked after everything. (I actually did this to replace one of the class files that I was including.) If I had done this for all the classes I needed to include, it would have triggered many more code changes for them (why this was a problem is a whole different story ;)

Comment: Have you tried to include them from the `build/classes` folder?

Comment: I understand the problem but what a but another `common-base` project? So `common` & `standalone` can be a dependent. And another question. You need the classes only at `runtime`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/) could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should do the trick:

```
from("${project(':common').buildDir}/classes/main") {
    include('com/classpath/ClassA.class')
    include('com/classpath/ClassB.class')
    include('com/classpath/ClassC.class')
    include('com/classpath/ClassD.class')
    include('com/classpath/ClassE.class')
}
```

But as I already stated in my comments. This classes are only available on runtime and you should probably create a new project (e.g. `base`) which is a dependency of `common` and `standalone`